# Read a message from a IBM MQ queue in a Azure logic app

Tags: azure, ibm-mq, azure-logic-apps

We need to read/get data from a IBM MQ queue in Azure. We decided to use Logic app, and personally have no experience using it.

We have these fields:

```
"QueueHost": "myport.com",
"QueuePort": "11111",
"QueueChannel": "Myqueue",
"QueueUserName": "myUserName",
"QueuePwd": "myPassword",
"QueueNameMyPerson": "a.b.c",
"QueueNameMyOrg": "a.v.b.x",
"QueueManager": "external"
```

As a trigger I choosed "recurrence" since I want a timed job. I then used "Recieve a message" and used above information, and added a .pfx cert to the logic app and set the thumbnail as well.

To see the data, I choosed to send an email with the content data and operation message to see if we get any hits but so far nothing. What would be the best connector? is "recieve a message" a correct step to use in order to connect with a IBM MQ queue? What would the "best" way to debugg/log all eventual data from the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Read a message from a IBM MQ queue in a Azure logic app

If you want to use MQ you can use only by this way:

[image]

To make this connector work, you need to attain some [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-mq?tabs=consumption#prerequisites).

You can refer this [MS-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/mq/#receive-message) too.

AFAIK, this is the only way and you need to know channel name, queue manager name and etc which need to connect to the connector.

> To see the data, I choosed to send an email

You do not need to send and email to check to see contents, you can directly check it is working or not in run history, here you might know where their is an error or why you are not receiving message like below:

[image]

When you click on them you will het to know what's  the issue, if you still cannot solve your issue, I would suggest you to raise a support request .

Comment: Yes, I have set everything but I get this error:  "The service provider action failed with error code 'ServiceOperationResourceNotFound' and error message 'Failed to find the TLS client certificate that matched thumbprint xxxx"

I have upladed the cert to a keyvault, doble checked the thumbprint is correct and have given the logic app read permissions to the keyvault. Have I missed something? Seems like the logic app cannot find the cert.

Comment: Have you clearly followed the [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-mq?tabs=consumption#authentication-with-tls-ssl-encryption) process, if you had then you wont get this error

Comment: The error is saying thumbprint or pass word or some part of certification process was wrong, try to check on certification, rest is the process which is normal for everyone, why dont you upload certificate directly to logic apps https://i.imgur.com/HnRamPY.png

Comment: Thanks. Issue was that I forgot to add a parameter in the configuration to load the cert.

Comment: Glad your problem is solved